# How to wait for specific time efficiently

Tags: python, interrupt, clock

Using Python on a Raspberry Pi, I need to automate making or breaking a contact (GPIO signal high/low) at set times in a day (e.g.: activate at 8:00 AM and deactivate at 5:00 PM), while still listening for an interrupt by pushbutton (So no cron unfortunately).

Is there a more efficient way than using `time.sleep(1)` until `time.time()` matches my specific time?
Is there an interrupt for this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What about a two script solution? One that performs the planned activities (or even two separate ones, one for the morning and one for the afternoon) which you can call via cron, and another script which just listens?

Comment: `time.time()` will make for a pretty sloppy solution.  How will it handle daylight savings?  Time zones?  etc.  It just tells you how many seconds it's been since the epoch.  `time.localtime()` could more easily tell you if you are inside a range of times though.

Comment: I would use datetime objects

Comment: Why not use the `sched` module?

Comment: @Carsten: That is actually a very elegant solution! I will probably use that.
@dhke: Well, thats is what the question is about. I don't know more efficient ways, so I didn't know about `sched` yet. Care to provide an example?